# How to setup gh-pages correctly

Tags: github-pages, mkdocs

I created successfully a very basic gh-page on [https://makanu.github.io](https://makanu.github.io/). The Repo just includes a `README.md`, a `LICENSE` and the most basic `index.html` I could imagine.

My problem is now, that I have a another [Repo](https://github.com/MaKaNu/rainbowdrinkinggame/tree/gh-pages) which includes a gh-pages branch which includes the files created with mkdocs. But for some reason [https://makanu.github.io/rainbowdringinggame](https://makanu.github.io/rainbowdrinkinggame) results in Error 404.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my failure. I didn't recognized the settings sections for pages. Since the Repo was created with cookiecutter I missed a few steps.

**The Solution:**

1. Open Repos settings
2. Open the `Pages` settings
3. Choose `gh-pages` branch as source

This worked for me and my setup with following cookiecutter-template: [enter link description here](https://mgancita.github.io/cookiecutter-pypackage/)

Others might need to change anything else, but the entry in the settings was the most important missing step on my side.

I also need to complete this and somehow apologize since I absolute missed the part in the documentation about repo configuration. I hope this might even so help others who struggle with this as I did.